# How do I reference an object, add a tween to it and put this in an Eventlistener in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, reference, event-listener

I'm having quite some trouble to try and get an app I wrote in [AS2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript#ActionScript_2.0) to [AS3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript#ActionScript_3.0). The reason I need to go to AS3 is something icky, so I won't go into detail about it.

I've got 90% of the application running with the new code.
Now I've come to the point where I have to convert this code from AS2,

```
function setAnimation(theObject,id)
{
    theObject.vensterid=id;
    theObject.onEnterFrame = function()
    {
        var myHoriTween:Tween = new Tween (this,"_x",Strong.easeOut,this._x,(130+((theObject.vensterid-frameno)*260)),1,true);
    }
}

setAnimation(venster0,0);
```

, to AS3. My attempt of doing this ended up like

```
function setAnimation(anObject,id) {
    var theObject = this[anObject];
    theObject.vensterid=id;
    function slideHorizontal(event:Event)
    {
            var myTween:Tween = new Tween (theObject,"x",Strong.easeOut,this.x,(130+((theObject.vensterid-frameno)*260)),1,true);
    }
    theObject.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,slideHorizontal);
}

setAnimation(venster0,0);
```

and gives me the following non-error (it doesn't show as a compiler error, but as output):

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
    at sliding_windows_as3_fla::SlideMenu_1/setAnimation()
    at sliding_windows_as3_fla::SlideMenu_1/frame1()
```

I think this is very strange since it doesn't say anything about which term (and there are quite a lot) and googling didn't find me an explanation either.

Comment: Hm. What is `frameno`? How it is defined and where?

Comment: frameno is number ranging from 0 to 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get the chance to test your code, because it's difficult to set up a context for it, but my thoughts would be:

1. You should declare the parameter types: `function setAnimation(anObject:Object,id:uint):void`. It's at least good practice.
2. `var theObject = this[anObject];` is completely unnecessary if your variable `anObject` is an object. I think `var theObject = this[anObject];` doesn't work, `theObject` ends up being null and that's why you get your error. If you have declared a variable called venster0, that is the instance of a class that extends Object, then you can pass the reference to it without any other trouble.
3. Depending on the object you work with, `theObject.vensterid=id;` might not work. The class that theObject instances must have the 'vensterid' property, or you will get `1119: Access of possibly undefined property vensterid through a reference with static type ...

Comment: as an answer to 2: venster0 is a movieclip with that instance name.
and to 3: it worked in as2. All I'm doing is creating a variable in a existing movieclip.

Comment: 2. then your code should work as is, if you define the parameter anObject:MovieClip or Object in the function header
3. you can't do that in AS3. your MovieClip class must have that property. If not, your venster variable should subclass another class

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem here is following string:

```
var theObject = this[anObject];
```

Just replace it with

```
var theObject = anObject;
```

I hope that's what you need.

Alternatively instead of

```
setAnimation(venster0,0);
```

you could pass an instance name (i.e. String):

```
setAnimation("venster0",0);
```

That will work because by `this['propertyname']` you are actually accessing Object's property by name.

Comment: And to declare everything properly in AS3 is a good practice. I mean declaring variable and parameter types everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Just going to throw out that using the built-in Tween classes in Flash/Flex is a pain.  Look into using Tweening libraries instead: Tweener, TweenLite, etc.  They are much easier to work with, and you don't have to worry about maintaining references until the Tween completes.